# How to handle connections using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0, google-cloud-sql

Below is my Hibernate.xml

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

and below is code from GenericDaoImpl

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl <T> extends HibernateDaoSupport  implements IGenericDao<T> {

   private Class< T > type;

   @Autowired
   public void setHibernateSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
   {
       setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
   }

   @Override
   public T save(T t) {
      Session session = getSession();
      session.saveOrUpdate(t);
      return t;
   }
}
```

Below is code from DaoImpl class

```
       Session session = (Session) getSession();
       Query executeQuery = session.createQuery("XXXXX");
        customerDetails = executeQuery.list();
        if(customerDetails !=null)
        {
            if(!customerDetails.isEmpty())
            {
                customerDomain = customerDetails.get(0);
            }
        }
```

I am using getSession() to execute query in DaoImpl classes. For every connection it is creating new connection  with database. I have given max connection size as 20 but that limit is crossing.  I am updating user's details via csv at that time it is crossing that max size limit. It is showing 556 connection to update 86 users only. How to handle connections using Hibernate .? Am i missing something.? or something is wrong in my code.?

Comment: What is your `getSession` method doing and how have you configured hibernate in your spring configuration.

Comment: No.I haven't done as such extra setting. can you tell me what extra settings need to do for configuration..?

Comment: Which settings? I asked for the implementation of your `getSession` method and how you configured the `SessionFactory` in Spring. You are using `@Autowired` so you have a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` or the likes somewhere in yuor configuration.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you don't close the Hibernate Sessions, hence the database connections never get released.

You shouldn't even use `HibernateDaoSupport`. You should use [HibernateTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html), which takes care of both transaction ans session management across @Transactional service boundaries.